# What is a Virtual Window in an aircraft?

Tags: aircraft-design, boeing, windows

I heard about **Virtual Windows** in the Dubai show, but I didn't really got it. What is it?

In a demo, when they opened the shields, I could just see the ground handling before taxing.

Search engines only gave me a [patent](https://www.google.com/patents/US20130169807), but I would rather learn about it laconically.

PS: Found in a triple seven.

---

I found a [video](https://youtu.be/ibqncXGMa4E?t=38s) where an english guy mentions them, but he doesn't seem to have a clue about their functionality.

Comment: @mins I disagree, we have plenty of questions about passenger accommodations.

Comment: I remember reading at one point the reason for this is that windows are difficult to build structurally and add a lot of weight to the aircraft. If the fuselage can just be an aluminum tube, that gives you better structural stability at a lighter weight. People probably feel too claustrophobic without windows, but a camera is a good compromise.

Comment: Does it show a virtual blue screen of death?

Comment: @Collin exactly what I was thinking. mins I started writing my question to the travel.se, but then thought it would better fit this site. Koyovis, not yet. ;)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

They are basically window-shaped screens, displaying a feed from a camera so the **middle aisle suits** (where the alternative is a wall) passengers can enjoy the "view".

> The most interesting thing to me are the virtual windows. First Class passengers in the middle suite will have a set of “windows” like everyone else, only theirs will show images from an outside camera.

https://travelupdate.boardingarea.com/virtual-windows-emirates/

Comment: Where is the camera pointed to?

Comment: @gsamaras outside, I suppose :) Probably to the side of the aircraft so the view is of an actual window.

Comment: Then what's the point? ;) I am thinking of something like the A380's camera view that the passenger can view on screen at the back of the front seat, where he can choose which view to be displayed! Thanks DeepSpace.

Comment: @gsamaras I think it will be pretty awkward to watch a front-looking feed from a "window". I'm sure it can make some people sick :)

Comment: @gsamaras Also, it is for the **middle** aisle suits. So the alternative is a wall.